# Injecting a webseal HTTP Header in Spring applications manually (JBOSS)

Tags: spring, jboss, http-headers, webseal

I am running spring applications in a JBOSS server inside a test machine. My application does some calls, for example it requires to access a webseal server which is not available in this machine, so I need to simulate its response by injecting the corresponding webseal http headers. I don't know where to start nor if you need more information to propose a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depend if your app wanna be a Client for webseal, or wanna be  a Backend app for webseal. If your app is a client, only recibe a Cookie with your Session ID. If your app is a Backend for web-seal(you are behind of a junction) you need recibe HTTP Headers "iv-user" and "iv-creds", this example help you to understand iv-creds:

[JSP Example - get Header Credentials Webseals](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/tivoli/tutorials/tz-tamauthapi/)